# what is the exact syntax for the nntp command LIST HEADERS

Tags: command, nntp

I have gone through all the RFC documentation for the syntax of command `LIST HEADERS`
I have found something at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3977#section-8.6 but it seems
to be incomplete.

There I got  :

LIST HEADERS [MSGID|RANGE]

There is a RANGE  parameter and   MSGID parameter ,my query is that how to specify the RANGE
with in command . Of course I have tried like

LIST HEADERS 20-120

for this server returning me  `501 no such list available`  not only for that range even for any ranges I am getting the same reply(even for different selected groups also).

Kindly anybody please let me know is there any problem in command syntax or in my understanding or problem with server ?. Am I specifying the range in correct manner  and what about MSGID.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server reporting the HDR capability?  This command requires that capability to be advertised by the server for it to be supported.